# Eclipse : how to structure all sub packages in a single one

Tags: eclipse, package

On my Project Explorer on eclipse, instead of getting this tree:

```
-src
 -com.presentation.interfaces
 -com.presentation.schemas
 -com.presentation.generetedClasses
```

I would like to consolidate all sub packages like this :

```
-src
 -com.presentation
```

How can i do this ??

Answer (score 4):

there is package presentation settings in eclipse where you can choose nested or full representation

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Graphical_Eclipse_FAQs#How_do_I_alter_my_package_representation_so_that_parent_packages_are_housing_child_packages.3F